# First item doesn't get animation with angular ng-class

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions, ng-class

It might be a simple question, but I'm stuck on this one for 3hours, I don't understand why the first element doesn't get animated.

In my html I have :

```
<md-button class="md-fab md-mini md-primary {{produit.dispos[0]
                        | ifNull:'disabled'
                        | ifTrue:'enabled'
                        | ifFalse:'disabled'}}" ng-class="{'no-shadow': hovered}"  ng-mouseenter="hovered = true" ng-mouseleave="hovered = false" aria-disabled ng-click="updateProduct(produit,btnDispo=0,btnProduct=produit.indexProduitBoutique,btnCommande=$parent.$parent.$index)">
                            V <span class="text">
                            disponible en boutique
                        </span>
</md-button>
<md-button class="md-fab md-mini md-primary {{produit.dispos[0]
                        | ifNull:'enabled'
                        | ifTrue:'disabled'
                        | ifFalse:'disabled'}} " ng-class="{'no-shadow': hovered}"  ng-mouseenter="hovered = true" ng-mouseleave="hovered = false" aria-disabled ng-click="updateProduct(produit,btnDispo=1,btnProduct=produit.indexProduitBoutique,btnCommande=$parent.$parent.$index)">
                            ?<span class="text">
                            disponible en boutique
                        </span>
                        </md-button>
<md-button class="md-fab md-mini md-primary {{produit.dispos[0]
                        | ifNull:'disabled'
                        | ifTrue:'disabled'
                        | ifFalse:'enabled'}}" ng-class="{'no-shadow': hovered}"  ng-mouseenter="hovered = true" ng-mouseleave="hovered = false" aria-disabled ng-click="updateProduct(produit,btnDispo=2,btnProduct=produit.indexProduitBoutique,btnCommande=$parent.$parent.$index)">
                            X
                        </md-button>
```

in my scss :

```
.md-button.md-fab {
top: 27px;
border-radius: 35px;
&:nth-child(1){
  &.enabled,&:hover{
    background: #4caf50;
    color: white;
  }
  &:hover{
    z-index:999;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    span{
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .text{
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
  .text{
    display: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: none;
  }
  -webkit-transition: width .3s, height .3s, background-color .3s, z-index 1s;
  transition: width .3s, height .3s, background-color .3s, z-index 1s;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
&:nth-child(2){
  &.enabled,&:hover{
    background: #ffc617;
    color: white;
  }
  &:hover{
    z-index:999;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    left:0;
    span{
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .text{
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
  .text{
    display: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: none;
  }
  position: absolute;
  left:80px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: width .3s, height .3s, background-color .3s, left .3s, z-index 1s;
  transition: width .3s, height .3s, background-color .3s, left .3s,z-index 1s;
}
&:nth-child(3){
  &.enabled, &:hover{
    background: #d32f2f;
    color: #fff;
  }
  background: white;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left:160px;
}
}
```

The thing is, if I remove the ng-class all works fine, if I put it only on the second and third, the second element doesn't animate.

Can't figure out why. If you guys have idea, or if it's duplicated please tell me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle I made with a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/thenalbachs/sx0uujgf/

I think all you are missing is CSS

```
transition: all
```

Fiddle code:

HTML

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="AnimationController">
  <div id="test" class="shadow" ng-class="{noShadow: disableShadow}" ng-mouseenter="disableShadow = true" ng-mouseleave="disableShadow = false">
  Test Text
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.shadow {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px 0 #888; 
}

.noShadow {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #888; 
}

#test {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

JS

```
function AnimationController($scope) {
  $scope.disableShadow = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man I'll take a look and come back to you if it works.

Comment: It's a bit better, now i do have the animation on the first element, but can't have it the first time i "hover" the button, gonna try to make a fiddle that have the same issue.